# How can I make button visible when Registration was successful?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

So I have a simple Starting Window, where buttons like: "Login", "Register", "Exit" and finally "Start Program" are.

- The "Start Program"-button is by default invisible.
- The "Login"-button doesn't work yet so forget about it.
- The "Exit"-button closes the program.
- The "Register"-button opens an new Window, where you can type in your username and password. This is then saved in a table connected with a SQL-Database.

I have a public bool that is called "LogIn" where as default is set to false. When I successfully register I set it to true. In my Startup.xaml I then check if the bool "LogIn" is true, if it is true it should set the visibility of my "Start Program"-button to visible. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**My Code:**

My Startup.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MiiUse.Startup"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiiUse"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Welcome To MiiUse" Height="500" Width="850"
        Style="{StaticResource Startup}"
        StateChanged="MaximizeWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Content="Start Program" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Start" x:Name="StartButton" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Exit" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Content="Register" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,16,0" Click="Button_Register"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,77,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.379,0.002" Click="Button_Login"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How it looks like:

[image: Starting-Window]

My Startup.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MiiUse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Startup.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Startup : Window
    {
        public Startup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Registration registration = new Registration();
            if (registration.LogIn == true)
            {
                StartButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            this.Close();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Exit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

        }

        private void MaximizeWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Register(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Registration registration = new Registration();
            registration.Show();

        }

        private void Button_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My Registration.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MiiUse.Registration"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiiUse"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Registration" Height="320" Width="370">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Enter your Username:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Enter your Password:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Submit"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Cancel"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How it looks like:

[image: Registration-Window]

My Registration.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MiiUse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Registration.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Registration : Window
    {
        public Registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool LogIn = false;

        private void Submit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string username = Username.Text;
            string password = Password.Password;

            if(Password.Password.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password can't be empty!", "Invalid Input!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                Password.Focus();
            }else if(Username.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username can't be empty!", "Invalid Input!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                Username.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connection_String))
                {
                    using SqlCommand sqlCommandGetTemplatesAndDrafts = new SqlCommand(@$"
                    Insert into tbl_Users (Username, Password) values('{username}','{password}')", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    sqlCommandGetTemplatesAndDrafts.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("You were successfully registered, and automatically logged in!", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                Close();
                LogIn = true;
            }
        }

        private void Cancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the `Visibility` property after the `Registration` window has been opened.

You could display the `Registration` window as a modal:

```
private void Button_Register(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Registration registration = new Registration();
    registration.ShowDialog();
    if (registration.LogIn == true)
    {
        StartButton.Visibility = registration.LogIn ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Also set `LogIn` *before* you close the window in Submit:

```
...
LogIn = true;
Close();
```

Another option would be to inject `Registration` with a reference to `MainWindow`:

```
private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow;
public Registration(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    InitializeComponent();
}
...
private void Submit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    _mainWindow.StartButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Close();
...
```

**MainWindow:**

```
private void Button_Register(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Registration registration = new Registration(this);
    registration.Show();
}
```

Buf if you are serious about WPF and XAML, you should learn [MVVM].

Answer (score 0):

convert your "LogIn" from bool to "Visibility" so instead of true or false we can mention Visibility.visible or Visibility.hidden. as follows:

```
public Visibility LogIn = Visibility.Hidden;
```

finally, bind your startup button visibility to this LogIn variable

So on successful completion of SQL :

```
LogIn = Visibility.visible ;
```

finally binding:

```
    <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Content="Start Program" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Start" x:Name="StartButton" Visibility="{binding LogIn}"/>
```

but this LogIn should either be in code behind or View model

but I think the best way to do it is to create a public class called helper and store these connection variables in it so that they are accessed throughout your application

create propoerty :

```
private Visibility _logIn;
public Visibility LogIn
{
  get => _logIn;
  set
  {
      _logIn= value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

and some wherer in your application initialise it to hidden

Comment: I understand your idea, but how can it bind to LogIn? It's in another file.

Comment: I tried this in Startup.xaml.cs, but the problem remains the same:

`Registration registration = new Registration();
            StartButton.Visibility = registration.LogIn;`

Comment: Even if he binds it, it won't change because first of all it's not a property but a field and also because it doesn't raise propertychanged event, so ui won't update.

Comment: added some additional information i think this is enough if not please let me know